# Smallest markup for "eligibleRegion = All Countries" with schema.org

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

In a project about video website, I have to prepare the information about countries eligible for viewing the video materials.

The markup for providing this information is like:

```
<span itemprop="eligibleRegion" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Country">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="DE" />
</span>

<span itemprop="eligibleRegion" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Country">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="FR" />
</span>
```

However, there are numerous amount of video products that are eligible in all countries. So, the obvious action is to repeat the above markup for about 200 times which seems not the best solution.

Is there possibility to achieve the same result [availability of the products in all countries] but with much more smaller amount of data?

Something like:

```
<span itemprop="eligibleRegion" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Country">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="[allCountries] or [allRegions]" />
</span>
```

---

**ONE POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

One possible solution comes into my mind is to use geoRadius from https://schema.org/geoRadius and specify a very big radius for it(?!)

```
<div itemprop="geo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/GeoCircle">
    <div itemprop="geoMidpoint" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates">
        <meta itemprop="latitude" content="42.362757" />
        <meta itemprop="longitude" content="-71.087109" />
    </div>
    <meta itemprop="geoRadius" content="[100000....]" />
</div>
```

However this doesn't seem very neat solution.

Answer (score 1):

As the [`eligibleRegion`](http://schema.org/eligibleRegion) property also expects `Text` as value, you could use something like:

```html
<meta itemprop="eligibleRegion" content="DE" />
<meta itemprop="eligibleRegion" content="FR" />
```

If you have more regions where it’s eligible than not, you might want to use the [`ineligibleRegion`](http://schema.org/ineligibleRegion) property instead.

If you want to convey that the content is eligible everywhere, you could of course simply omit any `eligibleRegion`/`ineligibleRegion` properties. That doesn’t explicitly make clear that that’s the case, but it might be implied.

Using [`GeoShape`](http://schema.org/GeoShape)/[`GeoCircle`](http://schema.org/GeoCircle) values that cover the whole Earth would be a way to make this explicit.

---

By the way, if it’s possible for you to use JSON-LD instead of Microdata, you could use something like this, which is of course more compact:

```json
"eligibleRegion": ["DE", "FR"],
```

Comment: Thank you **@unor**: but the problem is we want to explicitly indicate the region _[as the majority of the videos are only available in certain countries]_. So, it's essential to explicitly define the countries - which in some cases are _allCountries_ in the world.

Comment: @user319730: I think you have no other (machine-understandable) option than listing all relevant ISO 3166 codes, or using all-inclusive `GeoShape`/`GeoCircle` values. -- If you were not required to go this way, you could use `ineligibleRegion` and provide only a single ISO 3166 code of a country that no longer exists.